# sensor_msgs/Image data to sensor_msgs/CompressedImage data

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, image, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an industrial camera (DVP interface), and I added some code in the driver to convert the cv image into ros image data. I want to use this camera to test the [fiducials package](http://wiki.ros.org/fiducials). But it needs to subscribe to a `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage` topic, and now the driver can only provide the `sensor_msgs/Image` topic. Is there any way to convert the `sensor_msgs/Image` data into `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage` data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320116/sensor_msgs/image-data-to-sensor_msgs/compressedimage-data/) by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2019-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there any way to convert the `sensor_msgs/Image` data into `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage` data?

yes: the `republish` node of the [image_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport#Nodes) package can convert between uncompressed and compressed images (between any registered transports actually).

Note: this will incur overhead, as it subscribes, compressed and then publishes messages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-04-02**:
Thank you! It solved my problem. This is my method:`rosrun image_transport republish raw in:=/usb_cam/image_raw compressed out:=/usb_cam/image_raw`. Before use this node, `ros-$ROS_DISTRO-image-transport` and `ros-$ROS_DISTRO-image-transport-plugins` should be installed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-02**:\

> ```
> out:=/usb_cam/image_raw
> ```

is that correct, or a typo?

I would not publish on the exact same topic. Or does `republish` add a subtopic (ie: `/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed`)?

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-04-02**:
Because my camera driver will only generate a `usb_cam/image_raw` topic, and `image_transport` node will generate a new topic `usb_cam/image_raw/compressed` based on the parameter `compressed` of `out`.

**Comment by [sunt40](https://answers.ros.org/users/40158/sunt40/) on 2020-10-19**:
How to republish sensor_msgs/CompressedImage data to sensor_msgs/Image data ? I use "rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed raw out:=/usb_cam/image_raw". But thereis no data.When I run "rostopic echo /usb_cam/image_raw", There is nothing. Where is the problem ?